# Serving static website in nginx, wrong path for static files

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to use `nginx` to serve a static website that was given to me. Its folder structure is like this:

```
static_website/
    index.html
    www.example.com/
    resources.example.com/
    uploads.example.com/
```

The `index.html` file in the root is the one generated by `httrack` and it simply contains a redirect to `www.example.com/index.html`.
Inside the folder `www.example.com` are all the `html` files, in the other two folders are the `css`, `javascript` and `image` files.

Here is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/static_website/www.example.com;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html;
    }

}
```

I can navigate through the pages, but the css, javascript and image files are not loaded.
The path to one of the css files inside the html is like this:

```
href="../resources.example.com/style.css"
```

The only way I managed to get this working was to have the have the url like this:

```
example.com/www.example.com/
```

This way, all the path are correct. I'd like to avoid this and have simply example.com.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try adding another `location` that matches all of the resource files, for example: `location ~ \.(css|js|jpg|png|svg)$ { root /var/www/static_website; }`

Comment: thanks, that was it. If you add it as an answer instead of a comment I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site was originally intended to operate with ugly URLs like `//example.com/www.example.com/`.

But the path-relative URIs for the resources should work just fine relative to `/`, you just need to provide a `location` block which matches `/resources.example.com/`.

For example:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/static_website/www.example.com;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    index index.html;
}
location /resources.example.com/ {
    root /var/www/static_website;
}
```

---

I originally commented that you should try this:

```
location ~ \.(css|js|jpg|png|svg)$ { 
    root /var/www/static_website;
}
```

Which achieves a similar goal, but Nginx will process prefix locations more efficiently that regular expression locations.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share my experience with this problem for others encountering similar issues as the solution was not so obvious to me

My setup and problem in particular had to do with cloudlflare settings which i was using to leverage TLS instead of handling it on the origin server for one of my 2 sites. if you are serving your site from a CDN that supports encryption and you use nginx on your origin consider the following setup:

```
# static1.conf
{ server_name static1.com; root: /var/www/static1/public; listen 80; listen 443; }

# static2.conf - no tls setup in nginx, figured id let cloudflare handle it
{ server_name static2.com; root: /var/www/static2/public; listen 80; }
```

**static1** was setup at the origin with letsencrypt to handle tls connections

**static2** was setup at the origin without any tls configuration

from left to right, here are the appropriate cloudlfare TLS modes which allowed me to access the correct files thru nginx

[image]

The distinction between **full** and **flexible** is that full mode lets the origin handle the certificate.

Initially I had the static2 site misconfigured as full, which lacked a listen directive for 443 causing nginx to serve static1 instead.

I realize the original question has nothing to do with cdn's or cloudflare but this scheme / protocol mismatch cost me a few hours and I am hoping to save someone else from similar grief

Honestly I am surprised nginx doesn't stick to matching on server_name and that oit implicitly matches on scheme as a fallback (or atleast appears to), even without a default_server specified - and without any meaningful messages in the logs to boot! Debugging nginx is a nightmare sometimes.